# Laravel: "Trying to get property 'comments' of non-object"

Tags: laravel

I setup an api resource collection for the post model, called PostCollection. I have a problem with my comments query for a post. Getting non-object for $comments. The comment table currently has no records.

```
$author = \App\Post::find(1);
$comments = \App\Post::find(1)->comments;

return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'media' => $this->media,
    'media_type' => $this->media_type,
    'likes' => $this->likes,
    'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    'updated_at'  => $this->updated_at,
    'author_avatar' => $author->setting->user_profile_photo,
    'author_profile_name' => $author->name,
    'author_user_name' => $author->setting->user_name,
    'visible' => true,
    'comments' =>  $comments,
];
```

In the post model, I have:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

In the comment model I have:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: This would suggest that you don't have a post in your database with an `id` of `1`. Do you get `null` if you do `dd($post);`?

Answer (score 0):

You should this

```
public function comments()
{
 return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

in your controller

```
$post = \App\Post::find(1);
$comments = $post->comments;
```

Comment: That is only needed if database column names are non-standard. There's no indication that this is the case here.